# The centre of a minimal nonabelian $p$-subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

Let $G$ be a nonabelian $p$-group and $H$ a minimal nonabelian $p$-subgroup of $G$. In some books (see for exemple Remark 1, p. 331 in the Book" Berkovich, Groups of prime power ordre, Vol. 3" ), it is deduced directly that $C_{G}(H)=Z(H)$ without any clarification. But I can't understand why this is true. Did I miss something?

I would appreciate any hints and comments. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Which books are you referring to? What have you tried?

Comment: I don't believe this statement. $G$ could be a direct product of a nonabelian group $H$ or order $p^3$ and any other $p$-group.

Comment: I'm upvoting because I have Berkovich-Janko in front of me and the OP is right, this is what it says. I'm looking at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Berkovich-Janko do say this, but they have made a leap. In this situation, $G$ is a non-abelian $p$-group of order $>p^4$, and *all* proper non-abelian subgroups of $G$ have centres of order $p$. Thus if $B$ is minimal non-abelian then $Z(B)$ has order $p$. Now, if $x\in C_G(B)$ then $H=\langle x\rangle\cdot B$ is a non-abelian subgroup and $x\in Z(H)$. But $Z(B)\leq Z(H)$, so $x\in Z(B)$. Thus $C_G(B)\leq B$.